# UPDATE DATA WHERE data with quote

Tags: php, mysql

```
UPDATE table_name SET name='rom' WHERE Country='ra'm'
```

I have old data with quote on it and i cannot use WHERE clause because of it. How can I use WHERE clause on it even by escape it considers as different. like ra'm is not equal to ra\'m.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes instead.

`UPDATE table_name SET name='rom' WHERE Country="ra'm"`

Comment: It says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm' WHERE Country="ra'm"' at line 1

Comment: I got the answer the double quote will work but we have to escape ra'm then it works. Thank you.